# PowerPoint - how to keep animations running when zooming in during a presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, zoom, animation

I am running a PowerPoint presentation that has several animations. At some points I need to zoom in during the presentation, either using ctrl-mouse wheel or using the magnifier in the presentation. The problem is that when I zoom, the animations stop.
Is there a way to keep the animations running during the presentation?
Resizing the whole presentation would be too time-consuming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerPoint animations stop due to two causes:

- You use a zooming tool which takes focus to itself. And when PowerPoint presentation window loses the focus, the animation stops until the focus is back.
- You use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+mouse wheel zooming which actually takes a screenshot of the slide for zooming operations so it is not updated until you zoom back to 100% size.

Solution:

Use an application which does not change the focus and does not zoom to a screenshot but to a live image. One of such applications is [ZoomIt from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/zoomit). It is free and it keeps PowerPoint animations running.

```
Ctrl+4 – Toggle Live Zoom (This keyboard shortcut can be adjusted in options.)
Ctrl+⯅ – Zoom in
Ctrl+⯆ – Zoom out (If at minimum, then turn off Live Zoom.)
```

There is **no** mouse zooming in Live Zoom.